# C# inheritance template and caste

Tags: c#, templates, inheritance, polymorphism

it's my first question, excuse my incompetence,

I am trying to declare an object that is created from the inheritance of the same class but it tells me that I cannot cast the object being inherited

```
abstract class BaseEntity{...}

abstract class BaseController<T> where T : Model.BaseEntity{...}

class DummyEntity : BaseEntity {...}

class DummyController : BaseController<DummyEntity> {...}
```

When I want to create an object, it indicates that it cannot be implicitly converted.

```
BaseController<BaseEntity> a = new DummyController();
```

Comment: What is `CowEntity`? I'm guessing that's a derived class from `BaseEntity` right?

Comment: Sorry my fault.

Comment: Your `DummyController` inherits from `BaseController<CowEntity>`, not from `BaseController<BaseEntity>`. Even if `CowEntity` (whose definition you don't show) inherited from `BaseEntity` (which I'm guessing was your intention), you'd still get the error

Comment: What you want is co-variance which is not available on classes.  If you create an interface like `IBaseController<out T> where T : BaseEntity` then you can cast a `IBaseController<DummyEntity>` to a `IBaseController<BaseEntity>` but note you can only do this if `T` comes out of methods defined in the interface or is the type of a read only property, it cannot be the argument of a method or a type of a writable property.

Comment: @juharr Indeed. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57936810/10883465). I don't think it's worth explain co- and contra-variance here because there are a lot of ressources out there which can do that better than me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that. This has something to do with [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Imagine the `BaseController<T>` has a method `Add(T entity)`.

Now you create an instance of `DummyController`. You can call `Add(CowEntity entity)` on this instance because `DummyController` inherits `BaseController<CowEntity>` so `T` is `CowEntity`.

Now if you were able to assign this to `BaseController<BaseEntity>` you would suddenly be able to call `Add(BaseEntity entity)` (because T is now `BaseEntity`, not `CowEntity` anymore).
This means you could add an instance of `ChickenEntity` (which has nothing to do with `CowEntity`, it's just another derived class of `BaseEntity`) to that base-controller which is actually an instance of `BaseController<CowEntity>`. Now suddenly an instance of `BaseController<CowEntity>` contains a `ChickenEntity`. You see that this doesn't make sense.

To solve this you need to read about [interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) and [covariance (and contravariance)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Hope this helps :)